# Change tag name for "flex" to "apache-flex"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Most [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox)-related questions are incorrectly tagged as [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex).

I know this because I do many of the corrections.

Flexbox is CSS. Flex is Apache.

An update I made to the [flex tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flex/info) several months ago, which highlights the difference with flexbox, has made no difference. It's clear that most people don't read beyond the tag name.

I suggest changing the name from [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) to [apache-flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flex).

Note that there are also tags for [flex3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex3), [flex4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex4) and a few other versions. Maybe these tags should be adjusted as well for consistency.

Comment: Just remember when you write css you say `display: flex`.

Comment: [Adobe was first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Flex), none of these tags should be renamed.

Comment: @HansPassant, Actually Macromedia was first with Flex, then Adobe purchased Macromedia, then Adobe donated flex to Apache. In terms of tag names, however, I don't think any of this matters. If Apache sells Flex to another company, at that point we could consider another tag adjustment. I think the focus should be on descriptive, unambiguous tag names.

Comment: (cont.) not on who was first.

Comment: @gunr2171: Obviously that's why people keep mistakenly using the [flex] tag. Doesn't excuse them from not reading tag wikis.

Comment: There's probably also some confusion with [flex-lexer], the GNU implementation of lex.

Comment: @jwodder I retag such questions on a regular basis.

Comment: @Michael_B Plus 1 ... and I will join forces and subscribe to the `flex` tag as well and correct the one's I find

Comment: There seems to be some [200 questions in flex that also have the CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflex%5D+%5Bcss%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0). Once these are all retagged, I'll rename the tag to apache-flex.

Comment: @BhargavRao, sounds good. Just look out for those questions that are correctly tagged with `flex` and incorrectly tagged with `css`. And in some cases, both tags do apply. I saw examples of these on a cursory review of the list you posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflex%5D+%5Bcss%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Bflash%5D+-%22actionscript%22&mixed=0 should probably be a better one?

Comment: Just went through 45 questions from your original list. All tagging is already correct. There is such a thing as Flex CSS (not flexbox, but Apache Flex). So I think you're okay to let them be, unless there's an tagging distinction between HTML CSS and FLEX CSS. @BhargavRao

Comment: Cool, I renamed the tag to [apache-flex]. Thanks for spending the past 3 years cleaning this up.

Comment: [Rename \[google-wave\] to \[apache-wave\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380028/rename-google-wave-to-apache-wave)