# Rename [google-wave] to [apache-wave]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

Google launched their Google Wave service in 2009. The extensibility provided by the API was a major part of the offering, and many questions were asked about it under the [google-wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-wave) tag. As a Google service, Wave was unsuccessful and [shut down in 2012](https://support.google.com/answer/1083134), but Google released the software as open source and [transferred maintenance to the Apache Software Foundation](https://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/2010/12/introducing-apache-wave.html) under the new name Apache Wave. The tag on Stack Overflow should be renamed [apache-wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-wave) to match.

If we're just going to pollute the internet with abandoned content that nobody will maintain or use, we're as pointless as the forums we replaced. If we're going to keep this content, let's at least categorize it under the name any remaining users will be using[.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380012/its-time-to-bury-digg)

Comment: I think they should make [[tag:google-wave]] a synonym of [[tag:apache-wave]] instead of a rename. Still a rename can be used.

Answer (score 7):

[It's a dead project now.](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/wave.html)  I don't see any reason that anyone would today have any questions about the technology or anything like that.

(To complicate things, even *while* it was in incubator status, it wasn't really treated all that well nor was there a lot of energy behind it.  The documentation was incomplete and I don't recall there being a version which would compile completely.)

My vote:  let's not bother with a retag.  May be worth a discussion about what to do about completely unsupported libraries, but retagging is akin to rearranging the chairs on the Titanic *after* it's on the bottom of the Atlantic.

Comment: The open source project existed under the Apache Wave name for years longer than it existed as Google Wave, and the code is *still available under that name*. The project is dead, but to the extent that the posts have any value to the internet, it's would be to people using the code under the name Apache Wave.

Comment: @JeremyBanks:  When that day happens, someone will inevitably use the [tag:apache-wave] tag, but *until* that happens, I'm not seeing any value in doing anything with [tag:google-wave].

Comment: We *have* had questions about it (for longer than we had questions about Google Wave). The [apache + google-wave tag combination was first used in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750984/apache-wave-api), and there have been several similar questions since. Several other questions reference Walkaround, which is a distribution of Apache Wave. People have used the Google Wave tag because it's what we had, not because it was the best fit.

Comment: @JeremyBanks:  An alternate take:  since 2010, when Wave actually became an Apache project, **no one wanted to create the new tag**.   It isn't like tag creating privileges weren't a thing back then. I'm surmising from the lack of a desire *then* to rename the tags as the fact that, well, no one is asking questions about this.  I do not feel it appropriate to expend energy on something that no one else cares about.

Comment: What energy? This is a thirty second operation for a moderator.  **If we're going to keep the content on the site, we should maintain it.** If we want to delete the obsolete content, I'd be fine, but the community doesn't seem clear if they want that.

Comment: That's a *big* if.  It's worth a separate discussion in and of itself since this isn't the first time this year that this has come up.  I feel as strongly about content curation as anyone else does, but I don't feel like we should be curating museum pieces.  If the library truly is no longer supported or no longer exists, what role do we really have?  That's a discussion which goes above both of our pay grades as it stands today.

Comment: That is reasonable. I am concerned that these bigger questions will never really be resolved, and I'd rather just make this change and move on. But I can probably at least wait until after the Digg discussion to see where things stand.